# QBoxLayout add QTextEdit full size and QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, boxlayout, qpushbutton

I wanna have a `QTextEdit` and `QPushButton` in a `QBoxLayout`, where the button takes as little size as needed and the textedit all the rest.

So far I came up with this.

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton();
button->setText("Button");

QTextEdit* textedit = new QTextEdit();

QBoxLayout* boxLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom);
boxLayout->addWidget(textedit, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
boxLayout->addWidget(button, 0, Qt::AlignLeading);

mUI->centralWidget->setLayout(boxLayout);
```

There is still a padding between the textedit and the button. How can I remove it?

[image: Screenshot of Layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove `Qt::AlignTop`:

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton();
button->setText("Button");

QTextEdit* textedit = new QTextEdit();

QBoxLayout* boxLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom);
boxLayout->addWidget(textedit, 0);
boxLayout->addWidget(button, 0, Qt::AlignLeading);

mUI->centralWidget->setLayout(boxLayout);
```

That worked for me fine

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`setStretch`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qboxlayout.html#setStretch) function.

```
boxLayout->setStretch(0, 1);
boxLayout->setStretch(1, 0);
```

**EDIT**

Use a [`QVBoxLayout`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qvboxlayout.html) instead:

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton();
button->setText("Button");

QTextEdit* textedit = new QTextEdit();

QVBoxLayout* boxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
boxLayout->addWidget(textedit);
boxLayout->addWidget(button);

boxLayout->setStretch(0, 1);
boxLayout->setStretch(1, 0);

mUI->centralWidget->setLayout(boxLayout);
```